# NaN appears when doing pivot table

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do a pivot table after reading a table and i get 'NaN' values for some columns when i should have figures.

Here is the code i run:

```
dfba = pandas.read_table('Fao_data_Bilan_Alimentaire_V2.csv',sep = ',' ,header=0) 
print(dfba.dtypes)

Code Domaine               object
Domaine                    object
Code Pays                   int64
Pays                       object
Code Élément                int64
Élément                    object
Code Produit                int64
Produit                    object
Code Année                  int64
Année                       int64
Unité                      object
Valeur                    float64
Symbole                    object
Description du Symbole     object
dtype: object

colonnes = ['Pays', 'produit', 'Année', 'Élément', 'Valeur']

dfbatemp = print(dfba.loc[(dfba['Produit']=="Abats Comestible") & (dfba['Pays']=="Afghanistan"), colonnes])

        Pays  produit  Année  \
399  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   
400  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   
401  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   
402  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   
403  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   
404  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   
405  Afghanistan      NaN   2013   

                                               Élément  Valeur  
399                                         Production   53.00  
400                           Disponibilité intérieure   53.00  
401                                         Nourriture   53.00  
402  Disponibilité alimentaire en quantité (kg/pers...    1.72  
403     Disponibilité alimentaire (Kcal/personne/jour)    5.00  
404  Disponibilité de protéines en quantité (g/pers...    0.77  
405  Disponibilité de matière grasse en quantité (g...    0.20
```

Here i can see figures for all éléments i have selected. But when i do the pivot table i get NaN values!

I can see as well that there is a NaN value in column 'produit' when i should have "Abats Comestible" when evrything looks fine in my csv file!!

I someone have an idea about that thanks a lot in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAsrF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve])). We can't help without seeing your code! Beyond that: you should **not** use screen shots. All this data can be represented as **pure** text. So please remove the images, and write up a small **text and code** only question instead!

Comment: Thank you for your help and recommandations

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting a bit further!